# Issue in loading saved Scala XGBoost model from AWS S3

Tags: scala, apache-spark, amazon-s3, xgboost

I having an issue in loading the saved Scala XGBoost model from AWS S3. Below is my code. The issue is that I am able to save the Scala XGBoost Model in AWS S3 but unable to load the model from AWS S3.

```
val trainingData = sqlContext.read.parquet(path1)

val testData = sqlContext.read.parquet(path2)

val OOTvalData = sqlContext.read.parquet(path3)

// number of iterations
val numRound = 200
val numWorkers = 4
// training parameters
val paramMap = List("eta" -> 0.023f,"max_depth" -> 6,"min_child_weight" -> 3.0,"subsample" -> 1.0,"colsample_bytree" -> 0.82,"colsample_bylevel" -> 0.9,"base_score" -> 0.005,"eval_metric" -> "auc","seed" -> 8,"silent" -> 1,"objective" -> "binary:logistic").toMap

println("Starting Xgboost ")

val xgBoostModelWithDF = XGBoost.trainWithDataFrame(path1, paramMap, round = numRound, nWorkers = numWorkers, useExternalMemory = true)

xgBoostModelWithDF.write.overwrite().save(path4)


#### I am getting error at the below step to load the model from S3 location
xgBoostModelWithDF1 = XGBoost.load(path4)
```

Comment: what's the error you are getting?

Comment: I am getting the error - error: value load is not a member of object ml.dmlc.xgboost4j.scala.spark.XGBoost.                                                               I am looking for some another option to load.

Answer (score 0):

I'm working with python and I do 2 things you don't.

1. I read the object from S3 and use .read(), Then I put it into pythons `bytearray`
2. I also initialize a Booster.

Here's the python example, hope you can transform it to Scala

```
import xgboost as xgb

# reading model from s3 (you do it your way)
prev_xgb_model = s3_handler.get_gzip_file_content(reading_last_model_key)

# use .read() and transform it into pythons bytearray
model_ba = bytearray(prev_xgb_model.read())

# initilizing a model
prev_model = xgb.Booster({'nthread': 4})

# loading the model
prev_model.load_model(model_ba)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be using XGBoostModel to load the model, not XGBoost